# Get normalised eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given the matrix:

$\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & -a \end{pmatrix}$

and I already calculated the eigenvalues $\lambda = \pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Now, I want to get the normalised eigenvectors, so that there norm is equal to 1. Unfortunately, I seem to be incapable of carrying out this cumbersome calculation. Does anybody know if there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: The eigenvalues should be $\lambda=a\pm ib$ but not $\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: sorry, had a typo in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lambda I-A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda-a&-b\\-b&\lambda+a\end{pmatrix}$$

Substituting in the above and forming tha corresponding homogeneous system (and pay attention to the fact that **only one equation** is needed (why?)) when:

$$\lambda=\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;\;\implies\;\;\;(\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a)x-by=0\iff x=\frac b{\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}y$$

Thus, we get two eigenvectors (one for each eigenvalues), for example

$$\binom{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}\;,\;\;\binom b{-\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}$$

Now, orthonormalize the above (why can you?) . Easier than this in the *general case* I can't do it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $x=\frac{b}{\pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2} - a}y$? And the eigenvectors modified accordingly?

Comment: I see your point now, @posilon: you're right, thanx.